# Summing values in a List

Tags: scala

I'm trying to write a scala function which will recursively sum the values in a list. Here is what I have so far :

```
  def sum(xs: List[Int]): Int = {
    val num = List(xs.head)   
    if(!xs.isEmpty) {
      sum(xs.tail)
    }
    0
   }
```

I dont know how to sum the individual Int values as part of the function. I am considering defining a new function within the function sum and have using a local variable which sums values as List is beuing iterated upon. But this seems like an imperative approach. Is there an alternative method ?

Comment: Doing the progfun course?

Comment: Also note List.sum for when you don't need to write your own sum function.

Comment: please change the correct answer to `list.sum` as the title of your question is 'Summing values in a List'

Comment: def sum(xs: List[Int]): Int = xs.reduce(_ + _)

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Here's the the "standard" recursive approach:

```
def sum(xs: List[Int]): Int = {
  xs match {
    case x :: tail => x + sum(tail) // if there is an element, add it to the sum of the tail
    case Nil => 0 // if there are no elements, then the sum is 0
  }
}
```

And, here's a tail-recursive function.  It will be more efficient than a non-tail-recursive function because the compiler turns it into a while loop that doesn't require pushing a new frame on the stack for every recursive call:

```
def sum(xs: List[Int]): Int = {
  @tailrec
  def inner(xs: List[Int], accum: Int): Int = {
    xs match {
      case x :: tail => inner(tail, accum + x)
      case Nil => accum
    }
  }
  inner(xs, 0)
}
```

Comment: Reading Odersky's *"Programming in Scala 2nd edition"*, it seems that Scala (now) detects tail-recursion automatically. `@tailrec` shouldn't be necessary. Quote: `Functions which call themselves as their last action, are called tail recursive. The Scala compiler detects tail recursion and replaces it with a jump back to the beginning of the function, after updating the function parameters with the new values.` (p 203). So as long as the last thing you do is calling yourself, it's automatically tail-recursive (ie. optimized).

Comment: In other words, your first code sample should be as efficient as the second.

Comment: @kornfridge, No, that is not correct.  The first example, regardless of whether it has the annotation, is *not* tail-recursive since the last thing is does is **add** `x` to `sum(tail)`; the second-to-last thing is does is make a recursive call to itself.  See how that differs from the second example where the call to `inner` happens *after* the addition.

Comment: \@kornfridge, If i remember correct the @tailrec annotation at least checks that your function is tail recursive and generates an error otherwise. At least thats how i understood it.

Comment: @tailrec is for the compiler, it checks if the function can be run without keeping the stack frame alive after the recursive call. If it can't the compiler can tell you about it.

Answer (score 113):

Also you can avoid using recursion directly and use some basic abstractions instead:

```
val l = List(1, 3, 5, 11, -1, -3, -5)
l.foldLeft(0)(_ + _) // same as l.foldLeft(0)((a,b) => a + b)
```

`foldLeft` is as `reduce()` in python. Also there is `foldRight` which is also known as `accumulate` (e.g. in SICP).

Comment: Not sure in which version **sum** was added to **TraversableOnce**, now you could simply do as 

**l.sum**

Answer (score 80):

With recursion I often find it worthwhile to think about how you'd describe the process in English, as that often translates to code without too much complication.  So...

> "How do I calculate the sum of a list of integers recursively?"
>
> "Well, what's the sum of a list, `3 :: restOfList`?
>
> "What's `restOfList`?
>
> "It could be anything, you don't know.  But remember, we're being recursive - and don't you have a function to calculate the sum of a list?"
>
> "Oh right!  Well then the sum would be `3 + sum(restOfList)`.
>
> "That's right.  But now your only problem is that every sum is defined in terms of another call to `sum()`, so you'll never be able to get an actual value out.  You'll need some sort of base case that everything will actually reach, and that you can provide a value for."
>
> "Hmm, you're right."  *Thinks...*
>
> "Well, since your lists are getting shorter and shorter, what's the shortest possible list?"
>
> "The empty list?"
>
> "Right!  And what's the sum of an empty list of ints?"
>
> "Zero - I get it now.  So putting it together, the sum of an empty list is zero, and the sum of any other list is its first element added to the sum of the rest of it.

And indeed, the code could read almost exactly like that last sentence:

```
def sumList(xs: List[Int]) = {
    if (xs.isEmpty) 0
    else xs.head + sumList(xs.tail)
}
```

(The pattern matching versions, such as that proposed by Kim Stebel, are essentially identical to this, they just express the conditions in a more "functional" way.)

Comment: Nice approach: simple, understandable, maintainable.

Answer (score 43):

You cannot make it more easy :

```
val list  = List(3, 4, 12);
println(list.sum); // result will be 19
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: What if the objects aren't numbers?

Comment: If the objects aren't numbers you can map the values in the object that you'd like to sum.  Example. You have a Sales Object. `class Sales(type: String, amount: Int)`. Now you have a list of Sales. `salesList: List[Sales]`. To get the sum of sales. `salesSum = salesList.map(_.amount).sum`

Answer (score 15):

Your code is good but you don't need the temporary value num. In Scala [If] is an expression and returns a value, this will be returned as the value of the sum function. So your code will be refactored to:

```
def sum(xs: List[Int]): Int = {
    if(xs.isEmpty) 0
    else xs.head + sum(xs.tail)

}
```

If list is empty return 0 else you add the to the head number the rest of the list

Comment: hmm I just saw that @andrzej-doyle posted the same code before me

Answer (score 5):

The canonical implementation with pattern matching:

```
def sum(xs:List[Int]) = xs match {
  case Nil => 0
  case x::xs => x + sum(xs)
}
```

This isn't tail recursive, but it's easy to understand.

Answer (score 3):

Building heavily on @Kim's answer:

```
def sum(xs: List[Int]): Int = {
    if (xs.isEmpty) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Empty list provided for sum operation")
    def inner(xs: List[Int]): Int = {
      xs match {
        case Nil => 0
        case x :: tail => xs.head + inner(xs.tail)
      }
    }
    return inner(xs)
  }
```

The inner function is recursive and when an empty list is provided raise appropriate exception.

Answer (score 3):

If you are required to write a recursive function using isEmpty, head and tail, and also throw exception in case empty list argument:

```
def sum(xs: List[Int]): Int = 
  if (xs.isEmpty) throw new IllegalArgumentException("sum of empty list") 
  else if (xs.tail.isEmpty) xs.head 
  else xs.head + sum(xs.tail)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 def sum(xs: List[Int]): Int = { 
  def loop(accum: Int, xs: List[Int]): Int = { 
    if (xs.isEmpty) accum
    else loop(accum + xs.head, xs.tail)
  }
  loop(0,xs)  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To add another possible answer to this, here is a solution I came up with that is a slight variation of @jgaw's answer and uses the `@tailrec` annotation:

```
def sum(xs: List[Int]): Int = {
  if (xs.isEmpty) throw new Exception // May want to tailor this to either some sort of case class or do something else

  @tailrec
  def go(l: List[Int], acc: Int): Int = {
    if (l.tail == Nil) l.head + acc // If the current 'list' (current element in xs) does not have a tail (no more elements after), then we reached the end of the list.
    else go(l.tail, l.head + acc) // Iterate to the next, add on the current accumulation
  }

  go(xs, 0)
}
```

Quick note regarding the checks for an empty list being passed in; when programming functionally, it is preferred to not throw any exceptions and instead return something else (another value, function, case class, etc.) to handle errors elegantly and to keep flowing through the path of execution rather than stopping it via an `Exception`. I threw one in the example above since we're just looking at recursively summing items in a list.

Answer (score 1):

```
def sum(xs: List[Int]): Int = xs.sum

scala> sum(List(1,3,7,5))
res1: Int = 16

scala> sum(List())
res2: Int = 0
```

Comment: And how is this recursive, as the OP requested?

Answer (score 0):

Tried the following method without using substitution approach

```
def sum(xs: List[Int]) = {

  val listSize = xs.size

  def loop(a:Int,b:Int):Int={

    if(a==0||xs.isEmpty)
      b
    else
      loop(a-1,xs(a-1)+b)
  }

  loop(listSize,0)
}
```

Comment: There is no condition where `xs.isEmpty` at the same time as `a != 0`.  The `isEmpty` test is redundant.

Comment: If I send an empty list then the result should be 0. In this condition, the xs.isEmpty will be true. a == 0 will be true when the list loop has reached the first element. FYI, this has passed all the test cases in Coursera. Is there anything I misunderstood ?

Comment: If `xs.isEmpty` then `a==0` is also `true`, it cannot be otherwise, so testing for the `xs.isEmpty` condition serves no purpose. In fact it adds unnecessary overhead. When summing a `List` of 1 million elements it will be called million-1 times. If you remove that test and only use `if(a==0)` you will always get the same result. Also, you don't need the `listSize` value. Invoking your loop like this `loop(xs.size,0)` is simple and easy to read and understand.